Locate and classify all local extreme values of the function $f(x)=x-2\sin x$.
The problem:
Locate and classify all local extreme values of the function $f(x)=x-2\sin x$. Determine whether any of these extreme values are absolute. Sketch the graph of the function.
The solution:
local max at $x=2n\pi -\frac{\pi}{3}$; local min at $x=2n\pi +\frac{\pi}{3}$ $(n=0, \pm 1, \pm 2,...)$

What I have tried:
$$f'(x)=0 \iff 1-2\cos x=0 \iff \cos x = \frac{1}{2} \iff x=2n\pi \pm \frac{\pi}{3}, n \in \Bbb Z$$
My questions:
What do the dotted lines in the graph in the solution mean? Why are the specific points $\frac{\pi}{3}$ and $\frac{5\pi}{3}$ drawn out? Were arbitrary values for $n$ chosen? For example $n=0$ and $n=1$, so that the points one chooses to observe are $x_1=2 \cdot 0 \cdot \pi - \frac{\pi}{3}=-\frac{\pi}{3}$, $x_2=2 \cdot 0 \cdot \pi + \frac{\pi}{3}=\frac{\pi}{3}$, $x_3=2 \cdot 1 \cdot \pi - \frac{\pi}{3}=\frac{6\pi}{3}-\frac{\pi}{3}=\frac{5\pi}{3}$, $x_4=2 \cdot 1 \cdot \pi + \frac{\pi}{3}=\frac{6\pi}{3}+\frac{\pi}{3}=\frac{7\pi}{3}$. And were these points plugged into a chart to summarize the positive/negative properties of $f'(x)$ and the increasing/decreasing behavior of $f(x)$?

It's not clear to me how any of your questions are actually related to the mathematics of the title problem. Graphs are mostly just visual aids, and so the purpose of a graph is largely subjective. All your questions basically amount to "why did the author make all these artistic decisions", which isn't something anyone can answer (except the author themselves).

If I had to wildly speculate... the answers to your questions are, in order: "the diagonal line is where $y=x$, the vertical lines correspond to the solutions", "because the author wanted to draw some solutions", "yes", and "yes". Based on these answers, hopefully you can see how these questions are largely subjective and not really related to the mathematics of the problem.

If you draw the graph using Desmos or any graph calculator, you will see that somehow the graph of $y=x-2sin(x)$ is "periodic" along the line $y=x$, which is the dotted line $y=x$ in the solution.
Indeed, we can do the rotation by angle of $-\pi/4$ radians to transform the given graph into the graph of
$$ y = \sqrt{2}\sin \left(\frac{y\sqrt{2}}{2}-\frac{x\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)$$
In the usual $Oxy$ coordinate, this function is periodic with periodicity $2\pi\sqrt{2}$, so you only need to find the local minimum/maximum of this function in the interval $[0,2\pi\sqrt{2}]$ and convert back to the origial graph by rotation, it will tell you the shape of the original graph. I think this explains why they chose two specific values $\pi/3$ and $5\pi/3$. Hope it helps. 
